# Upgrading 8 speed Shimano 105 to 11 Speed Shimano 105

Tags: shimano, groupsets

I'm thinking about going to from 8 speed Shimano 105 to 11 speed Shimano 105-5800.

I know I'll definitely have to change my cassette, chain, rear derailleur and my right shifter.  But what about my crankset?  My current chain is 3/32 inches wide and my new chain would have to be narrower so what if it doesn't fit on my crankset?  Is that possible?

Comment: Do a cost/benefit analysis - figure the raw cost of the 105 11-speed parts, subtract that from the cost of a new bike, and see if you could get the difference by selling-on your old bike.  Parts are expensive.

Comment: Many 8-speed bikes have dropouts 125mm apart whereas modern ones have them 135mm apart. You would need 135mm.

Answer (score 6):

> I'll definitely have to change my cassette

Shimano 11 speed road cassettes require wider freehub body. You have several options here:

1. Get a new rear wheel or hub that supports 11 speed road cassettes.
2. Get a replacement 11 speed freehub body if there are any (most likely not).
3. Get a Campy freehub body and Campy 11 speed cassette instead of 5800.
4. Get [this Token cassette](http://www.tokenproducts.com/comps/drivetrain/11-10-cassette). It's an 11 speed road cassette that fits 10s freehub body.

> But what about my crankset? My current chain is 3/32 inches wide and my new chain would have to be narrower so what if it doesn't fit on my crankset? Is that possible?

11 speed chains are narrower on the outer side and same width inside. I'd first try to run older front shifter/derailleur/crankset and see if performance is acceptable. Also note that 5800 front shifter is compatible only with 5800/6800/9000 front derailleurs in case you are going that way.

Comment: So you're saying I can probably leave my crankset, front derailleur and left shifter but I'll have to replace cassette, chain, rear derailleur, right shifter and hub?

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is a little old...the crankset won't work. The spacing between the chainrings for 8 speed is large enough that the 11 speed chain can slip and jam in between them. At first it may seem to work, but it will jam occasionally when shifting.